# How to top and tail data from NHS or ONS using pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm playing with Pandas to look at alcohol-related admissions from https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/documents/LAPE_Statistical_Tables_for_England_2021.xlsx

I've got a bit of code that sort of looks like this:

```
 df = pd.read_excel("../LAPE_Statistical_Tables_for_England_2021.xlsx", sheet_name="1.3", skiprows=5)
df = (df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns"),
      df.dropna(how="all", axis="rows")
)
df
```

The results look like this:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Admissions  Number of admissions per 100,000 population6    Admissions.1    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.1  Admissions.2    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.2  Admissions.3    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.3  ... Admissions.7    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.7  Admissions.8    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.8  Admissions.9    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.9  Admissions.10   Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.10 Admissions.11   Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.11
1   E92000001   ENGLAND7    976420.0    1810.0  713550.0    2810.0  262870.0    940.0   938620  1770    ... 635060.0    2570.0  235020.0    860.0   841760  1620    614050  2530    227710  840
3   NaN Unknown 5100.0  0.0 4360.0  0.0 730.0   0.0 5260    0   ... 4370.0  0.0 620.0   0.0 5220    0   4460    0   760 0
5   E12000004   EAST MIDLANDS   86990.0 1820.0  63300.0 2790.0  23690.0 970.0   81060   1720    ... 54360.0 2470.0  20760.0 870.0   67800   1480    48930   2260    18870   800
7   E07000032   Amber Valley    2630.0  1900.0  1860.0  2810.0  780.0   1110.0  2280    1670    ... 1500.0  2350.0  610.0   890.0   2040    1550    1450    2330    590 880
8   E07000170   Ashfieldⁱ   2550.0  2010.0  1830.0  3050.0  710.0   1090.0  2550    2030    ... 1650.0  2810.0  620.0   970.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
382 Sources NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
383 ● Hospital Episode Statistics, NHS Digital - D...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
384 ● Public Health England - Attributable fractio...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
385 ● Mid-year Population Estimatesin England, The...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
387 Hospital Episode Statistics (HES) Copyright © ...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
363 rows × 29 columns
```

I can change the column names manually but I want to drop rows where column Unnamed: 1 contains all upper case characters.

I ideally want to drop all the attribution rows at the bottom. Is that possible with pd.read_excel()?

UPDATE: yes, it is possible to skip the footer with skipfooter in pd.read_excel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can drop the rows whose value in `Unnamed: 1` consists entirely of uppercase characters. Note that I've also adjusted your code dropping NaN's as the original version returned a tuple of `DataFrames` instead of applying both `.dropna()` on the same `DataFrame` (I assume you wanted to apply both operations on the same `DataFrame`).

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name="1.3", skiprows=5)
df = (
    df
    .dropna(how="all", axis="columns")
    .dropna(how="all", axis="rows")
)

print(df['Unnamed: 1'].head(n=5).to_markdown(index=False))

# | Unnamed: 1    |
# |:--------------|
# | ENGLAND7      |
# | Unknown       |
# | EAST MIDLANDS |
# | Amber Valley  |
# | Ashfieldⁱ     |

df = df.loc[
    df['Unnamed: 1'] != df['Unnamed: 1'].str.upper(),
    :
]

print(df['Unnamed: 1'].head(n=5).to_markdown(index=False))
# | Unnamed: 1   |
# |:-------------|
# | Unknown      |
# | Amber Valley |
# | Ashfieldⁱ    |
# | Bassetlaw    |
# | Blaby        |
```